# Elastic Search - Conditional projection

Tags: elasticsearch

I know that we can use projection in Elastic Search to influence which fields of the document are returned or not - similar to projection in other areas. However, can I also do a projection in such a way that fields - or for my case more importantly array elements - are filtered out if they do not meet a certain condition?

Let's say the documents indexed in ES look like this:

```
{
    "identificationString": "XYZ-123",
    "localElements": [{
        "name": "table",
        "languageCode": "en"
    }, {
       "name": "mesa",
       "languageCode": "es"
    }],
    "author": "Jon Snow",
    "department": "Wood Work"
}
```

To create this index I used e.g.:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/my-index?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "identificationString": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "localElements": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "name": { "type": "text"  },  
          "languageCode": { "type": "text"  }  
        }
      },
      "author": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "department": {
        "type": "text"
      },
    }
  }
}
'
```

To index the above mentioned document I used:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/my-index/_doc/?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "identificationString": "XYZ-123",
    "localElements": [{
        "name": "table",
        "languageCode": "en"
    }, {
       "name": "mesa",
       "languageCode": "es"
    }],
    "author": "Jon Snow",
    "department": "Wood Work"
}
'
```

If I only want to return e.g. `identificationString` and `localElements` I can do it like that:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/my-index/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }, 
    "fields": ["identificationString", "localElements.*"], 
    "_source": false
}
'
'
```

or like that:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/my-index/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "_source": ["identificationString", "localElements.*"]
}
'
```

However, is there also a way to only return those localElements that satisfy a certain condition? E.g. only those with a specific `languageCode`? I would like to filter out those elements that do not fulfil a certain condition - I do not want to see them in the response. Of course I could do this logic in my application itself but I was wondering whether Elastic Search can do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-inner-hits.html) along with the nested query

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "localElements",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "match": {
              "localElements.languageCode": "es"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67805874",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.6931471,
        "_source": {
          "identificationString": "XYZ-123",
          "localElements": [
            {
              "name": "table",
              "languageCode": "en"
            },
            {
              "name": "mesa",
              "languageCode": "es"
            }
          ],
          "author": "Jon Snow",
          "department": "Wood Work"
        },
        "inner_hits": {
          "localElements": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 0.6931471,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "67805874",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "localElements",
                    "offset": 1
                  },
                  "_score": 0.6931471,
                  "_source": {
                    "name": "mesa",
                    "languageCode": "es"         // note this
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: That looks quite promising. It could work for my use case. I will investigate a bit further and then come back to you.

Comment: @KarlMeierBE have you tried bu using `inner_hits` ? Please let me know if this worked for you ?

Comment: It seemed it was kind of working yes. It is not exactly the behaviour I would like to have as then you need to parse out the inner hits and deal with these in a certain way. I would prefer if I could do a conditional projection and just get back the document with the according field directly. I will wait a bit to see if anybody else finds a way to achieve that and if not - I will accept your answer as the solution

Comment: I accepted it now. It is not exactly what I was looking for due to the explained reasons but I will accept anyway as it seems there is no real solution to what I want :)